# Validation Engine not working in jquery latest version

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

Validation Engine is not working for latest version of jQquery (v1.10.2). It is working only in V1.8.2... So when I am dynamically updating latest JS version there might be a problem.

So can anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have jQuery Validation Engine working fine with jQuery 1.10.1 and 1.10.2

However I know historically there was one or two versions of jQuery it didn't work well with - but I think that was 1.7.xx  somthing.

Have you made sure you are using the latest version of the plugin currently 2.6.1 I believe

http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/